# What happens by [-2] in Array?

Tags: python, list, types

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(set(map(int, input().split())))
arr.sort()
print(arr[-2])
```

I was expecting to get the 2nd highest number from a list . But I can't understand how the -2 works

Comment: There's no array in your question, just a list.

Comment: This question should be answered in any Python list tutorial. SO is not a substitute for learning the basics.

Answer (score 0):

A negative index counts backwards from the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.sort(reverse=True)` and than access the second highest number with `num[2]`. `-1` is the far side (the end of the list), `-2` is the second last.